# Update MySQL database column where metadata is copied from one row to another

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I've been presented with a situation where I need to update data in a MySQL database column where I copy the data from the column of one row of related data to the same column but in a different row.
It is a Wordpress/WooCommerce database table called `"wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta".`  I want to be able to copy the value of the `meta_value where meta_key=_product_id to meta_value column where meta_key=_variation_id whereever the order_item_id numbers match`.
So, in the screenshot you see that all the `order_item_id` values are all the same (they are all 8) - I want the 172 in the meta_value column to be copied to the `meta_value column where meta_key=_variation_id`

https://snag.gy/DMrfXu.jpg

I want to be able to update these by using the _product_id values because I have around 180 products and I can do this rather quickly.  I can not, however, do this by including the order_item_id numbers because I have tens of thousands of orders.

The variation ID numbers all came through with the value of 0 after a migration from OpenCart.  I'm hoping there is a way to run a  query like this.

Comment: You can try something like: SET column=(Select value from table where row=val Limit 1)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know how I would be able to construct that for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer to my own question.
This is what worked for me:

```
UPDATE wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as wp1, wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as wp2 
SET wp2.meta_value = replace(wp2.meta_value,'0','172') 
WHERE wp1.order_item_id = wp2.order_item_id AND wp1.meta_key = '_product_id' 
AND wp2.meta_key = '_variation_id' AND wp1.meta_value='172' AND wp2.meta_value='0';
```

I hope this might help someone in the future.